# NSNumber for MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID to NSString and back again

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mpmediaquery

I'm looping through all the songs from an iPhone's music library using the following code:

```
NSArray * songs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[MPMediaQuery songsQuery] collections]];

for (MPMediaItemCollection * item in songs){

    NSString * persistentID = [[[item representativeItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID] stringValue];
    // Do something with it.
}

[songs release];
```

Pretty basic stuff.

I'm getting the PersistentID as an `NSString` because I need to write it to an XML file (for transmission over a network to another device). Hence the reason I can't just leave it as an `NSNumber`.

The other device will then ask for the iPhone to play a track by transmitting the PersistentID back again.

At this point, the iPhone has an `NSString` of the PersistentID of the track it should play.

It would be combersome to loop through every song again and compare PersistentIDs until I find the track I want, so I'm trying to use the `MPMediaPropertyPredicate` to have the iPhone search for me.

I'm using the following code for the search:

```
MPMediaPropertyPredicate * predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:persistentID forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];

MPMediaQuery * songsQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
[songsQuery addFilterPredicate:predicate];

if ([[songsQuery items] count]){

    MPMediaItem * item = [[songsQuery items] objectAtIndex:0];
    // Play item.
}

[songsQuery release];
```

Where `persistentID` is the `NSString` from earlier.

Weirdly, this works for some songs, not for others. i.e, sometimes the `items` array is not empty, even though I'm passing an `NSString`, not an `NSNumber`.

I'm wondering if there's a way to convert my `NSString` back to the `NSNumber` it came from, and how I can do that.

**UPDATE**: I've tried the NSNumberFormatter, I've also tried something like:

```
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[persID floatValue]];
```

I've tried all the standard ways of doing it without prevail.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is working pretty well, no problems so far:

```
unsigned long long ullvalue = strtoull([persistentID UTF8String], NULL, 0);
NSNumber * numberID = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithUnsignedLongLong:ullvalue];

MPMediaPropertyPredicate * predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:numberID forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];
[numberID release];

// And so on.
```

Hope this helps anyone else who ran into this problem.

Comment: +1 for the solution. Without converting to NSNumber i tried to input NSString to predicate and returning 0 items. more than half a day gone trying to debug. Your solution helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to convert an `NSString` to an `NSNumber`. To do this, you can use a `NSNumberFormatter`. Take a look at the `numberFromString:` method.

[NSNumberFormatter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000202-BCICBCFA)

Comment: I've editing my question to include what I've tried. The number formatter was one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do the same thing.  The Query Predicate for MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID has to be passed in as NSNumber.  I found this answer on converting NSString to NSNumber from another StackOverflow post:

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber * persistentIDasNumber = [f numberFromString:persistantID];
[f release];

MPMediaPropertyPredicate * predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate   predicateWithValue:persistentIDasNumber  forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something very similar and worked out the following:

```
NSNumber *musicIdentifier = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] numberFromString: persistentID];
MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] initWithFilterPredicates:[NSSet setWithObject:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:musicIdentifier forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID]]];

MPMediaItem *item = query.items.firstObject;
```