# How to get a MPMediaItem using URL

Tags: ios

I only know song's URL, but I want to get it's artwork.Can anyone help to answer this?

If I can get the MPMediaItem, then can use this to get artwork:[mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork].

Comment: Has this URL been loaded from the `MPMediaItem` previously? Or is it just an iTunes URL or similar?

Comment: This URL is loaded from MPMediaItem and saved into database.

Comment: You may want to use the answer to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890500/url-to-mpmediaitem